# Conditional statements to show a different component React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

i want to create a function or a conditional statement you can say that can show different components based on "If the user have bought products" then show the products components otherwise show "just a simple text like browse or buy products."

```
 <div>
 <Bookscard />
 </div>
```

so this is my component, inside the component the purchased products are being mapped. Can i get a conditional statement that can either show this component like ( if user.courses is greater than or equal to 1 then show the component otherwise show a text ) something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div>
 { user.courses.length > 0 &&
 <Bookscard />
 }
 { user.courses.length > 0 ||
 <NoResults />
 }
</div>
```

Or you can keep consistency with && by:

```
<div>
 { user.courses.length > 0 &&
 <Bookscard />
 }
 { user.courses.length == 0 &&
 <NoResults />
 }
</div>
```

Comment: thank you brother, and lastly what to add in this condition that if the length is less than 1 or no products that show a h1 like browse

Comment: Yup, you can do it all with `||` , I've edited my answer to have this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up to @Antoine Baqain's answer, you could use ternary operator too, like this:

```js
<div>
 { user?.courses?.length > 0 ? <Bookscard /> : <NoResults /> }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good too, i will try this